# how to get the SP app's URL in sharepoint designer workflow 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, designer-workflow

I want to use the SP APP's url in designer workflow-2010,but am unable to get it. so am bit curious to know that,is it feasible???

Comment: What do you mean by app's url?

Comment: Means i want to access Sp hosted App URL from same site collection in that Workflow